# Adobe Analytics cross-domain with Experience Cloud ID

Tags: cross-domain, adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics, web-analytics

I ask your help to better understand if my cross-domain tracking (Adobe Analytics via Experience Cloud ID) is working properly. To me it seems not.
As you see in screenshot 1, my visits might come from Domain A and go, within the same session, to Domain B. We're collecting data, from both domains, to the same AA Report Suite.
The Experience Cloud ID Service is active, in the same way, to both configurations (same mc org id, as you see).

Into Analytics Workspace (screenshot 2) I created a fallout analysis to show how visits move from Domain A to B. The Analysis is based on two segments including visits that in turn include hits for domain A or B.
I expected to see Domain A visits to be distributed also to the Domain B, but it seems not. No visits are going there...how could it be?
Am I missing something with the Experience Cloud ID configuration ?

Thanks so much

[image: screenshot_1]

[image: screenshot_2]

Answer (score 1):

The out of box setup for Adobe Experience Cloud Visitor ID Service requires the browser to be able to access a third party call to a subdomain under demdex.net, and then stores a cookie containing the user's identifier under demdex.net domain. [See Adobe's KB for more detailed description of the process.](https://helpx.adobe.com/marketing-cloud-core/kb/MCID/CrossDomain.html)

If the browser for whatsoever reasons cannot save or read the cookie, then as the visitor goes from site A to site B, the JavaScript JS library (i.e. Visitor.js) will keep requesting on a set of identifiers from demdex.net or failing contacting demdex.net generate a set of identifiers locally.

Comment: Thanks @Robert . Only Google Chrome was used for testing, do you think it's not able to access 3rd-parties ?

Comment: Any extensions used?